# ¿Como sumo el total de varias calificaciones?

Tags: mysql, sql

En mi DB realicé la búsqueda de un alumno y me arrojó las materias que ha cursado(24 materias), calificación de cada materia y los créditos de cada una(1 materia = 10 creditos). Ahora bien, lo que quiero es sumar los créditos y que ya no me salgan individual sino sumados en una sola fila (240 creditos).
***mi consulta al momento***

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Usuario.usuario,
              Usuario.actividad,
              Usuario.fktipousuario,
              Usuario.fkedousuario,
              Persona.paterno,
              Persona.materno,
              Persona.nombres,
              Persona.curp,
                      Mail.email,
                      Telefono.numtel as telefono,
                      Delegacion.nombre as delegacion,
                      Asignatura.modulo,
                      Asignatura.tipo,
                      Asignatura.creditos,
                      Asignatura.descripcionasig,
                      Inscripcion.calificacion,
                      Acta.fechaplat,
                      Grupo.grupo
        FROM usuario AS Usuario
        LEFT JOIN persona as Persona ON(Usuario.idusuario = Persona.fkusuario)
        LEFT JOIN direccion as Direccion ON(Persona.idpersona = Direccion.fkpersona)
        LEFT JOIN colonia as Colonia ON(Colonia.idcolonia = Direccion.fkcolonia)
        LEFT JOIN mail as Mail ON(Persona.idpersona = Mail.fkpersona)
        LEFT JOIN telefono as Telefono ON(Persona.idpersona = Telefono.fkpersona)
        LEFT JOIN delegacion as Delegacion ON(Colonia.fkdelegacion = Delegacion.iddelegacion), 
                  alumno AS Alumno, 
                  inscripcion AS Inscripcion, 
                  acta AS Acta, 
                  asignatura AS Asignatura, 
                  grupo AS Grupo 
        WHERE Usuario.idusuario = Alumno.fkusuario
          AND Inscripcion.fkalumno = Alumno.idalumno
          AND Inscripcion.fkgrupo = Grupo.idgrupo
          AND Inscripcion.fkacta = Acta.idacta
          AND Inscripcion.valida = 1 
          AND Acta.fkgrupo = Grupo.idgrupo
          AND Grupo.fkasignatura = Asignatura.idasignatura
          AND Asignatura.idasignatura NOT   IN (1,2,3)
              AND Usuario.usuario LIKE 'ead1410002'
            GROUP BY Asignatura.modulo DESC, 
                     Asignatura.creditos ASC, 
                     Acta.fechaplat DESC) Historial
```

Answer (score 2):

Haciendo sum al credito y agrupando por id puedes hacer lo que necesitas, tendrias que tener el id en el subquery para poder agrupar por id en el query principal, algo asi....

```
    SELECT SUM(creditos) AS Credito, idpersona, nombres FROM (SELECT Usuario.usuario,
              Usuario.actividad,
              Usuario.fktipousuario,
              Usuario.fkedousuario,
              Persona.paterno,
              Persona.materno,
              Persona.nombres,
              Persona.curp,
              Persona.idpersona,
                      Mail.email,
                      Telefono.numtel as telefono,
                      Delegacion.nombre as delegacion,
                      Asignatura.modulo,
                      Asignatura.tipo,
                      Asignatura.creditos,
                      Asignatura.descripcionasig,
                      Inscripcion.calificacion,
                      Acta.fechaplat,
                      Grupo.grupo
        FROM usuario AS Usuario
        LEFT JOIN persona as Persona ON(Usuario.idusuario = Persona.fkusuario)
        LEFT JOIN direccion as Direccion ON(Persona.idpersona = Direccion.fkpersona)
        LEFT JOIN colonia as Colonia ON(Colonia.idcolonia = Direccion.fkcolonia)
        LEFT JOIN mail as Mail ON(Persona.idpersona = Mail.fkpersona)
        LEFT JOIN telefono as Telefono ON(Persona.idpersona = Telefono.fkpersona)
        LEFT JOIN delegacion as Delegacion ON(Colonia.fkdelegacion = Delegacion.iddelegacion), 
                  alumno AS Alumno, 
                  inscripcion AS Inscripcion, 
                  acta AS Acta, 
                  asignatura AS Asignatura, 
                  grupo AS Grupo 
        WHERE Usuario.idusuario = Alumno.fkusuario
          AND Inscripcion.fkalumno = Alumno.idalumno
          AND Inscripcion.fkgrupo = Grupo.idgrupo
          AND Inscripcion.fkacta = Acta.idacta
          AND Inscripcion.valida = 1 
          AND Acta.fkgrupo = Grupo.idgrupo
          AND Grupo.fkasignatura = Asignatura.idasignatura
          AND Asignatura.idasignatura NOT   IN (1,2,3)
              AND Usuario.usuario LIKE 'ead1410002'
            GROUP BY Asignatura.modulo DESC, 
                     Asignatura.creditos ASC, 
                     Acta.fechaplat DESC) Historial
GROUP BY idpersona, nombres
```

Comment: Hola Carlos, te agradezco tu respuesta, me ha servido de mucho pero el problema es que haré la suma de créditos de varios alumnos y cuando ingreso varias matriculas me da el total de créditos en un solo registro y lo que quiero es el total de créditos de cada alumno por separado.
ejemplo: AND Usuario.usuario IN ('ead1410002', 'ead1410001')
en ves de que me de ead1410002 = 240, ead1410001= 240 me lo da total =480
¿crees poder ayudarme?

Comment: Cambia el Sum del select por este otro: (SUM(creditos) AS Credito, usuario), al final el group by lo cambias por: (GROUP BY usuario), ahi deberia funcionar (le quitas los parentesis)

Answer (score 0):

Hola convierte tu `Sub Query` en tu `Query` principal he intenta esto:

```
SELECT Usuario.usuario,
    Usuario.actividad,..,
    SUM(Asignatura.creditos)  
        OVER(PARTITION BY Usuario.usuario 
                ORDER BY Usuario.usuario) AS [CreditosXUsr],
    Asignatura.descripcionasig,
    Inscripcion.calificacion,
    Acta.fechaplat,
    Grupo.grupo
FROM .....
```

Solo funciona en `SQL SERVER 2008` o posteriores